# How to merge two model in one fieldset in django admin module

Tags: django, django-admin, customization

I have two table like below

**tableA**

- field1
- field2
- field3

**tableB**

- field4
- field5

**Group 1**

field1: textfield (tableA)

field3: textfield (tableA)

field5: textfield (tableB)

**Group 2**

field2: radiobutton (tableA)

field4: textfield (tableB)

I tried the solution like form inlines but I want the grouping of fields in one form, not a separate inline form.